# Using camera and gallery to post photo

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

Hey I'm currently using the bones of an insta dupe for swiftui for my app and I'm trying to get the "post" option to show after I pick a picture/take a photo.

code:

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack{
                Button(action: {
                    self.isShown.toggle()
                    self.sourceType = .photoLibrary}, label: {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "plus.square")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 160, height: 160)
                        
                        Text("Upload image")
                            .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .semibold))
                
                    })
                Divider()
                    .padding(5)
                Button(action: {
                    self.isShown.toggle()
                    self.sourceType = .camera}, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "camera")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 160, height: 160)
                        Text("Camera")
                            .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .semibold))
                    
                    })
                .padding()
                                                .sheet(isPresented: $isShown) {
                                                    A(isShown: self.$isShown, myimage: self.$image, mysourceType: self.$sourceType)
                                                }

            }
            
            NavigationLink(destination:
                            PostDetailsView(
                                viewModel: viewModel,
                                selectedImage: $selectedImage,
                                selectedTab: $selectedTab
                            ),
                        isActive: $showDetailsView) {
                EmptyView()
            }.hidden()
            
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
            struct A: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
                @Binding var isShown: Bool
                @Binding var myimage: Image
                @Binding var mysourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType
    
                func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<A>) {
    
                }
                func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<A>) -> UIImagePickerController{
                    let obj = UIImagePickerController()
                    obj.sourceType = mysourceType
                    obj.delegate = context.coordinator
                    return obj
                }
                func makeCoordinator() -> C {
                    return C(isShown: $isShown, myimage: $myimage)
                }
            }
    
            class C: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
                @Binding var isShown: Bool
                @Binding var myimage: Image
    
                init(isShown: Binding<Bool>, myimage: Binding<Image>){
                    _isShown = isShown
                    _myimage = myimage
                }
    
                func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
                    if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                        print(image)
                        myimage = Image.init(uiImage: image)
                    }
                    isShown = false
                }
                func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
                    isShown = false
                }
            }
    
}
extension UploadPostView {
    func loadImage() {
        guard let selectedImage = selectedImage else { return }
    
        showDetailsView = true
    }
}`
```

Could really use some help here!! I've tried googling it myself and learned the camera doesn't work in simulator so I put it on my phone but the "post" option doesn't show up.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please format your code neatly and limit it only to the relevant parts so that it's easier to figure out what might be the problem. Also, your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with Firebase so you might want to edit the title as well.